# How to recreate .select()?

Tags: ruby, select

I'm trying to recreate the `#select` method. So far, I have array portion working, but when I try to call `#my_select` on a Hash, I get an empty Hash.

FYI, for starters, I had to recreate my own `#each' method. Here's that.

```
module Enumerable 

 def my_each
    i = 0
    while i < self.size
        yield(self[i])
        i += 1
    end
    self
 end
```

Now, here's the `#my_select` method I created:

```
 def my_select
    if self.instance_of?(Array)
        ret = []
        self.my_each do |item|
            ret << item if yield(item)
        end
        ret
    elsif self.instance_of?(Hash)
        ret = {}
        self.my_each do |key, value|
            if yield(key,value)
              ret[key] = value 
            end
        end
        ret
    end
  end
end
```

...my input/output...

```
> h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300 }
> h.select { |k,v| k == "a"}
=> {"a"=>100} 
> h.my_select { |k,v| k == "a"}
=> {}
```

Comment: Could you please also show my_each method?

Comment: I got it working by replacing `my_each` with `each`. So `your_each` is wrong or misspelling `Enumerable` could also be a problem.

Comment: I got the same result as @oldergod.  If you would like to edit your question to include `my_each`, we could see if the problem lies there.  Consider using `case self`, then `when Array`, `when Hash`.

Comment: `my_each` iss not handling `Hash`

Comment: Enumerable is pretty much built on top of `each`: define your own `each` method, `include Enumerable`, and away you go. I think your `my_each` approach is counter productive, you should build your `select` implementation on top of `each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could change `my_each` to handle `Hash` as well?

```
def my_each
    if self.instance_of?(Array)
      i = 0
      while i < self.size
          yield(self[i])
          i += 1
      end
      self
    elsif self.instance_of?(Hash)
      i = 0
      arr = self.to_a
      while i < arr.size
          yield(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])
          i += 1
      end
      self
    end
  end
```

Comment: You should replace `yield(arr[1], arr[2])` by `yield(arr[i])`

Comment: Then it would yield `[k,v]`. But `Hash.each`, yeilds `k,v` right? or am I confusing stuff?

Comment: Instead of yielding `k,v`, you can just yield `[k, v]` as an array. If you still want to yield `k,v`, you should replace `yield(arr[1], arr[2])` by `yield(arr[i][1], arr[i][2])`

Comment: I was wondering how `each` might be implemented for a `hash`.

Comment: I found the correct code to be `yield(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])`. I was returning 3 blank lines for `h.my_each {|k,v| puts v }` until I decremented the nested array count by 1. Secondly, is there a way to code `my_each` with k,v? I tried `[k,v]` but terminal returns an error - `'undefined local variable or method'`

Comment: Yes Im sorry made a mistake again. Edited. What do you mean `my_each` with `k,v`? The above code does it right?

Comment: I meant, is there a way to write the code without specifying a nested array? How could I use the Hash's key and value properties?